# My chat application deletes the current text inside a text file when adding a contacts details, how can I fix this?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

My chat application deletes the current text inside a text file when adding a contacts details, how can I fix this?

```
Private Sub btnAddContact_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddContact.Click

    If lblFileName.Text = "No file selected!" Then

        MsgBox("No file selected!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)

    Else

        If System.IO.File.Exists(fileName) = True Then

            Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName)

            objWriter.WriteLine(tbUsername.Text & "," & tbIP.Text & "," & tbFirstName.Text)
            objWriter.Close()
            MsgBox("Added Contact!")

        Else

            MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")

        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName, True)
```

Comment: It would be great if you can provide a description of your solution. Thanks!

Comment: This instruction simply sets the `append` parameter to **true**. So, `if the file exists, it will be opened for appending contents to the end of it. If not, the file will be created.` This **solves the issue** once and for all.